# How to simply add an Add Event button to FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I've read the docs and while it may seem simple to some, it's like reading another language to me. I have very little experience with coding this way. All I want to do is have an "add Event" button like the one in the demo https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent-demo

However I am not sure where to put the code. When I paste it in my index.html, my website is just a blank page. Is there a specific part of the html where I need to paste the code to add the button? All the code I am using for my project has come from fullcalendar.io

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to add a button to the html page, then you must put it in between the body tags in the .html page.  Then you can add an event listener to add javascript through the script tags and have it update properties or interact with the button.  And the code through the pen given by your example is all javascript so you can either add it through script tags or link to it on a separate page.

```
<html>
<body>
<button type="submit" id="btn">add Event</button>
<script>
 ...all the code given in the code pen here.
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked! If anyone is following the code on FullCalendar, I added a <body> tag at the end of my index.html with the code from the Add Event demo in between.

Comment: I'm glad it worked!  Could you please mark it as the answer please!